# Bash: String spliting issue

Tags: string, bash, split

I had created a following code:

```
function file_name {

  if [ -n $1 ]; then
    parts=$(echo -e $1 | tr "/")

    for a in ${parts}; do
       echo $a
    done
  fi
}

file_name("this_is/a_test/string")
```

When I run it, I get following error:

```
./test: line 138: syntax error near unexpected token
 `"this_is/a_test/string"'

./test: line 138: `file_name("this_is/a_test/string")'
```

Comment: parenthesis are use to create a subshell.

Comment: Once you've removed the parentheses, run your script through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) for other useful corrections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure bash version without `echo`, `tr` and pipe.

Work fine with filenames containing spaces.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

function file_name {
    local str="$1"
    local token=
    while [[ "${str}" =~ / ]]; do
        token="${str%%/*}"
        #if [[ "${token}" != "" ]]; then
        echo "${token}"
        #fi
        str="${str#*/}"
    done
    if [[ -n "${str}" ]]; then
        echo "${str}"
    fi
}

file_name "this_is/a_test/string"
```

Remark:

- Uncomment `if [[ "${token}" != "" ]]; then` and `fi` if you want to squeeze empty names provoked by double slashes (`//`) or by a path who start by a slash

Answer (score 1):

1. bash function calls does not require `()`
2. `tr` needs a second argument `tr "/" " "`

---

Since you don't have any whitespaces, I'd recommend using command substitution to split the string:

```sh
function file_name {
    if [ -n $1 ]; then
        for part in ${1//\// } ; do 
            echo "$part"
        done
    fi
}

file_name "this_is/a_test/string"
```

```
this_is
a_test
string
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3BCsIwEETv@Yoh9CpLz/0UlRDbjVnQjTTrqfTbY9OLcxrePJhHrLm19NXZpCiSvDhofDM25wBJuOKiGEbcJ1hm7RRIZcUnrgY5tm0kuhFhx4Sl4BR6eM4FfuieP@FSlI@SxO3O/Z@8ZalBKsVgXI2qraJP39oP)

Comment: Hello. Nice code, but as you wrote, it doesn't allow filenames with spaces, with could case problems by files may contain them. Any ideas to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function file_name {

  if [ -n $1 ]; then
    parts=$(echo -e $1 | tr "/" " ")

    for a in ${parts}; do
       echo $a
    done
  fi
}

file_name "this_is/a_test/string"

# writes:
# this_is                                                                                                  
# a_test                                                                                                   
# string
```

There are two problems in your code. The first is what you are seeing in the error message right now. The reason is that the function is not called properly. Bash handles functions like mini scripts so the syntax for passing arguments to functions is like you pass arguments to scripts.

The second error which you will see after this is corrected is a missing argument to `tr`. I assumed you want to replace `/` with a space for the `for` loop to work properly later.